# Regular expression to find duplicate records

Tags: regular-expressions, duplicate-management

I would like to use a regualr expression on certain fields to detect possible duplicate records. for example the regx will detect all account records with the account name matching for than 50 %.possible duplicate acct names: AMC NY, NY AMC, NY & NYC, AMC LA.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the standard salesforce duplicate management tool.  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_prevention_map_of_tasks.htm&language=en_US

If your logic is too complex to support the duplicate management then you may need to write custom apex to achieve your result.

Comment: my requirement is not covered with the standard SFDC Duplicate management tool..that is why i want to explore the regx

Comment: I don't it being possible to have one regex that would meet all your criteria as it is not a clear pattern.   You could construct a regex expressions for each pattern you wish to validate AMC NY, NY AMC...  then uses these patterns to validate your data.